# VirtualBox Guest Additions Broke 3d Acceleration on Debian Installation

Tags: linux, virtualbox, debian, virtual-machine

I have installed debian-9.3.0-amd64-xfce via downloading the .iso from the torrent link on the debian website, and confirmed the md5.

After installation, I followed the [instructions on the Virtualbox website for installing guest utilities on Debian](https://virtualboxes.org/doc/installing-guest-additions-on-debian/).

After following these instructions and resetting my debian virtual machine, I can no longer enable Machine > Settings > Display > Acceleration: Enable 3D Acceleration. If I enable this feature, when starting the VM, I am only presented with a black screen, and cannot perform any actions. If I disable this feature, the VM starts normally.

How can I have 3d acceleration and VirtualBox Guest Additions with a Debian installation on Virtualbox with a Windows 10 64bit host?

Comment: This is common issue with VB.  You will just have to wait till either your distro updates its drivers, or VB updates theirs.

Comment: As of August '18 I am having the same problem using the most recent version of VB